# Violation issue 'load' handler took 7473ms

Tags: angularjs

> [Violation] 'load' handler took 7473ms
>
> [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 77ms
>
> angular.js:5255 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 73ms
>
> [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 38ms

angular.js:5255 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 73ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 38ms

I'm trying to render more data's in a html file,that tooks more time to display data in the screen.I don't know why the violation issue comes when the data trying to load.Currently i'm using angular 1.3 version and jquery 2.1 version.Is there any problem with the version and to render the data.
I'm using more no.of bindings for the rendered data in a html file.
can anyone help me out with the exact solution and how to optimize the data or how to render the data?

Comment: You would need to post your code first. `Violation` is just a warning, not an error

Comment: I know violation is just a warning,it takes 7473ms to load the data's,i'm just using more than one ng-repeat and lot number of bindings,if i reduce bindings the time reduces according to biniding.